# Start tmux session immediately after killing tmux server

Tags: tmux

If I run

```
tmux kill-server ; tmux new -d -s test
```

Sometimes it works, and sometimes I get `lost server` or `no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default`.

If I do

```
tmux kill-server ; sleep 0.1; tmux new -d -s test
```

Then it always works.  But I suspect it might fail on a heavily loaded system.

What's happening during that `sleep 0.1` and is there a way to explicitely wait for it?

Answer (score 0):

Inline execution of commands will not always work seamlessly reason is:

- If you run first command which need time to execute by system.
- And second command is dependent on it and if required same/partial resources.

It is good to have delay between inline commands. System will be as responsive as we think some time :)

Answer (score 0):

`tmux kill-server ; tmux new -d -s test`
with
`tmux kill-server && tmux new -d -s test`

You want to make sure `tmux kill-server` succeed in order to start a new server.

It seems `tmux kill-server`, I experienced the same situation. Looks like it's run as a daemon and when it returns, it doesn't mean the server is killed.

Comment: I'm no longer in a position to test this, but I can't imagine why && would make a difference.  The kill-server wasn't *failing*, it was just ending itself before the server was fully down.

Comment: First how do you know if it wasn't failing? `;` doesn't care about the error code. Second, it's true that `kill-server` doesn't wait for all the processes to be killed before returning.